# Using ArcGis for displaying location on OneMap

Tags: android, maps, arcgis

I am using the ArcGis for the first time in my android application(java).

I have got the X and Y co-ordinates of a location by "one map" http://www.onemap.sg/API/Help/RESTExamples.aspx,

now I want t display this point as a red dot in Map.

X-26005.0765
Y-30007.0973

Does anyone know any  tutorial to follow. I saw the "Hello Map Tutorial".

Can Anyone direct me to the tutorial or documentation with example.

Asmita

Answer (score 2):

You must use Graphics layer to add a graphical representation of your point.
The code below is an example were you print a point in the coordinates that you gaved.

```
public class Test extends Activity {

// View elements
MapView map;
GraphicsLayer measures = new GraphicsLayer();
Point point;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    // Get elements of the view
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    map.addLayer(measures);

    Point point = new Point(26005.0765, 30007.0973);

    measures.addGraphic(new Graphic(point,new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.RED,10,STYLE.CIRCLE)));

    map.zoomTo(point, 0);
}
```

}